# Compare two structs like array in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to compare 2 structs of the array type in Golang in order to know if having struct1 obtained from web scrapping is equal to struct 2, which is data fetched from the database.
It is the way that I have thought to be able to know if there has been a change between the external web and my database.

The structs is:

```
type Exchange struct {
    Name          string    `gorm:"Column:name" json:"name"`
    Buy           float64   `gorm:"Column:buy" json:"buy"`
    Sell          float64   `gorm:"Column:sell" json:"sell"`
}
```

The result after consult is from scrapping:

```
&[{Dólar 38.5  41 } {Euro 38.82  43.57 } {P. Argentino 0.05  0.35 } {Real 6.95  8.95 }]
```

From web

```
&[{Dólar 38.5 41} {Euro 38.82 43.57} {P. Argentino 0.05 0.35} {Real 6.95 8.95}]
```

My Code:

```
    fmt.Println(exchanges)
    dbExchanges := getExchangesFromDB()
    fmt.Println(dbExchanges)
    if exchanges == dbExchanges {
        fmt.Println("is equal")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("no is equal")
    }

    fmt.Println("Struct equal: ", reflect.DeepEqual(exchanges, dbExchanges))
```

Result:
no is equal

Struct equal:  false

Comment: Can you clarify what is wrong with your code and how you would like it to behave differently? The two examples you shared are not the same, and the result of your code says they are not the same. Have I misunderstood? Producing an example on https://go.dev/play may be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @icio, I need comparate both struts for return if is equal or no.

Comment: I can't understand why they are not the same

Comment: Comparing structs in Go is straightforward. It looks like you are comparing pointers to slices of structs, which is not.

Comment: I've voted to close the answer because it's a "typo" although it's stretching the meaning of typo - but I think the question doesn't have much value to future users of stackoverflow. The values are pointers to slices rather than slices. Pointers compare equal only when they point to the same value. The solution is for your code (that's not included in the question) to use slices rather than pointers to slices, or for the comparison to compare `*exchanges` and `*dbExchanges`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first if you are comparing the memory address of the two variables instead of theirs values. In the second if clause (using reflect.DeepEqual) you are comparing their values.